# I don't know how to make a while loop last until a list doesn't have any values left

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to recreate the card game "War" in python and cant figure out how to loop the code under the comment until every value in the list is gone. So basically the code generates a shuffled deck of cards and pops the cards from the list. I want to have the code repeat until all the cards have been popped from the deck and I have no idea how to do that.

```
import random
def shuffled_deck():
  deck = list(range(2, 15)) *4
  random.shuffle(deck)
  return deck


userdeck = shuffled_deck()
print("welcome to War!")
user1 = input("Player-1 name: ")
user2 = input("Player-2 name: ")
u1points = 0
u2points = 0
drawturns = 0
# - I want to loop the segment of code under this comment

usercard = userdeck.pop()
u1card = usercard
print(user1 + ": " + str(u1card))
usercard = userdeck.pop()
u2card = usercard
print(user2 + ": " + str(u2card))
if u1card > u2card:
  print(str(u1card) + " is greater than " + str(u2card) + ".")
  print(user1 + " won this round.")
  u1points +=1
elif u2card > u1card:
  print(str(u2card) + " is greater than " + str(u1card) + ".")
  print(user2 + " won this round.")
  u2points +=1
else:
  print("It's a draw, try again.")
  while u1card == u2card:
    drawturns +=1
    usercard = userdeck.pop()
    u1card = usercard
    print(user1 + ": " + str(u1card))
    usercard = userdeck.pop()
    u2card = usercard
    print(user2 + ": " + str(u2card))
    if u1card > u2card:
      print(str(u1card) + " is greater than " + str(u2card) + ".")
      print(user1 + " won this round.")
      u1points +=1
      u1points + drawturns
    elif u2card > u1card:
      print(str(u2card) + " is greater than " + str(u1card) + ".")
      print(user2 + " won this round.")
      u2points +=1
      u1points + drawturns
    else:
      print("It's a draw, try again.")
    if u1card == u2card == False:
      drawturns = 0
      break
```

Comment: `while len(userdeck) > 0:`?

Comment: @Barmar could also reduce it to simply `while userdeck:`

Comment: thanks that worked

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
while len(userdeck)>0:
```

or, you can write smartly as:

```
while userdeck:
```

This is because an empty list is considered as `False`, whereas a non empty list is considered as `True`. So, when userdeck is empty, `while` loop will assume it to be `False` case, so the loop will stop. This same concept can also be applied for `if` statements.